# Layout pixels and Canvas pixels different?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-linearlayout, surfaceview

So, I have Framelayout witch has SurfaceView(0), and xml layout(1). My layouts height is 200px(below), and I'm drawing 200px high rectangle for testing. For some wierd reason, layout seems to take up more space tan rectangle. How could I make it so, that layout would be in rectangle, regardless of screen size or density? (I hope this not too confusing...)

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="200px"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:id="@+id/game_ui
"
style="@style/AppTheme">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:text="Points"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="500"
        android:textSize="60sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
```

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:text="Time"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="500"
        android:textSize="60sp"
        android:gravity="center"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Drawing a Rectangle:

```
Graphics g = game.getGraphics();
    g.clearScreen(Color.BLACK);   
    g.drawRect(0, 0, wildth, 200, Color.GREEN);
    //draws 200px high rectangle onto surfaceView
```

Result is this:

http://tinypic.com/r/sb6h55/8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use hardcoded pixels in your layout or code.

Use density independent pixel (DP) in your layout.

```
android:layout_height="200dp"
```

Convert pixels in code to DP

```
final int height = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 200, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
final int width = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 200, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

Graphics g = game.getGraphics();
g.clearScreen(Color.BLACK);   
g.drawRect(0, 0, width, height, Color.GREEN);
```

For more information read everything on

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#screen-independence